# How to order an array only after it has been filled

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift4

```
   func getOkToDownload(response:AcloseCarsToDownload?, error : Error?) -> Void {

        if let response = response {
           self.response = response
            if response.status == "OK" {
                if let carsDownloaded = response.cars {
                    var number = numberCars / (categories?.count)!
                    number = number == 0 ? 1 : number

                 let sortedArray = carsDownloaded.sorted {
                            distance(from: currentLocation!, to: $0.location!) < distance(from: currentLocation!, to: $1.location!)
                    }


                /*    let firstPlace = sortedArray.prefix(1) */




                  cars.append(contentsOf: sortedArray.prefix(number))

            }
               self.tableView?.reloadData()
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: response.status, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.loadPlaces(true)

                    }
                }))
                 self.present(viewController: alert)
                }
            isLoading = false
        }
        else {
            print("response is nil")
        }
    }
```

I'm using this function to create a list `cars.append(contentsOf: sortedArray.prefix(number))` of downloaded items from a server; and i want that this list is ordered from nearest to fairest item so i thought to order it by adding

```
let sortedArray = carsDownloaded.sorted {
                            distance(from: currentLocation!, to: $0.location!) < distance(from: currentLocation!, to: $1.location!)
                    }
```

but the problem with this solution is that it sorts the list at each call and the result is not the desired one, i wish that only once finished and the array is filled, the list will be ordered. How can i do?

This is the func i used for the call

```
func loadCars(_ force:Bool) {

        if !force {
            if !canUpdate() {
                return
            }
        }

         if(force){
        print("load")
        iUpdating = true
         for category in categories! {

            CloseCars.getCloseCars(by: category?.name ?? "berl", coordinates: currentLocation!, radius: radius, token: self.response?.nextPageToken, completion: getOkToDownload)

       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can collect all responses to one array and check when number of elements is equal to the number of elements in categories and then use your sort function. Or you can use Rx

Comment: can you give me an example with code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in comment you could count number of responses and compare it with the number of categories, and only then perform your sort function. I haven't tested code, but you could try something like this

```
    var counter: Int = 0
var sortedArray: [String] = [] {
    didSet {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func getOkToDownload(response:AcloseCarsToDownload?, error : Error?) -> Void {
    counter += 1
    guard let response = response
        else {
            print("response is nil")
            return
    }
    if response.status != "OK" {return}
    guard let downloadedCars = response.cars else { return }
    allCars.append(contentsOf: downloadedCars)
    if counter != categories.count {return}
    let sortedArray = allCars.sorted {
        distance(from: currentLocation!, to: $0.location!) < distance(from: currentLocation!, to: $1.location!)
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not going to order only by categories right? because my original problem is that with my code the final array is ordered only  by categories but i do not want it, i want that all items regardless of the category of membership are ordered from nearest to fairest

Comment: as you can see from code, sorted array doesn't depend on categories, it sorts all the cars you got from response